# How to send a Rest request through VPN using cURL in windows?

Tags: windows, curl, port, vpn

**Problem definition**: I want to send a *rest* request to an API that blocks my real *ip* address. I used a **VPN** that can change the ip (I checked it by any browser) but the masked ip leaks when I try to send the rest request. It means although the browser shows masked ip, the rest request knows my real ip.

Here is a simple rest request using cURL that returns the ip:

```
curl https://api.ipify.org?format=json
```

**Tried solution**: I have tried to send a port that is used by VPN. for example in this situation, the rest request should be like this:

```
curl -x http://localhost:<PORT> https://api.ipify.org?format=json
```

but I don't know what the port is used by the vpn I use. Also, I don't know is it a true solution or not?
thanks for all the answers and help.

Comment: A real VPN will route all traffic through it, even curl.